# How to assign one row column value to another row column based on null value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
    Col1    Col2    Col3     Col4    Col5
    A123    13500  2/03/19    0      NaN
    B123    2000   3/04/19    0     Distinct
    C123    500    8/09/19    1      Match
    D123    100    11/01/19   1      NaN
    E123    1350  2/03/19      2         NaN
    F123    2000   3/04/19    2     Match
    G123    500    8/09/19    3      Distinct
    H123    100    11/01/19   3      NaN
```

I want to loop through the rows based on `Col4` and update `Col5(NaN)` row accordingly.

That is, when I pick rows where `Col4` is 0, I want to update the `Col5` based on other row column value

```
Output:

    Col1    Col2    Col3     Col4    Col5
    A123    13500  2/03/19    0     **Distinct**
    B123    2000   3/04/19    0     Distinct
    C123    500    8/09/19    1      Match
    D123    100    11/01/19   1      **Match**
    E123    1350  2/03/19      2        **Match**
    F123    2000   3/04/19    2      Match
    G123    500    8/09/19    3      Distinct
    H123    100    11/01/19   3     **Distinct**
```

Comment: `based on other row column value`, which other...?

Comment: which column value.

Comment: I pick two rows based on Col4, in the example I will pick A123 and B123 rows. And I want to update the null column (Col5) in row A123 with another row B123 Col5 value

Comment: Agree with @Minato. But for starters, you don't want to loop. Any such value replacement should be done through a vector operation. You need to specify "for this value in `Col4`, I want to see this value in `Col5` to replace the `NaN` value." If you can't clarify expected input/output, we can't help.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the function np.where. I am assuming that you want to assign the value 'Distinct' to `Col5` when `Col4 = 0` and 'Match' when `Col4 = 1`. Then you code will be:

```
df['Col5'] = np.where(df.Col4==0, 'Distinct', 'Match')
```

Of course, you can adapt the code for whatever conditional statements you need

Comment: Col4 is used to just pick two rows, it can be from 0 ,1,2...so on. Col5 can have values as Distinct/Match. I want to copy the Col5 value to the other row (with same Col4 value) if its NaN. I hope I am clear in explaining

Comment: @user12277274 I think you need to provide a more clear example of the input (values in `Col4` and `Col5`) and the output that you want. It needs to be fairly comprehensive, including all cases you're wishing to cover.

Comment: @user12277274 Yes, please make the example a bit more clearer. Probably you can add more rows to your input and show what your expected output is

Comment: modified  example

Answer (score 0):

From your logic, it appears that you wish to map values of 0,3 in `Col4` to "Distinct" in `Col5`, and values of 1,2 to "Match". You only want to update `NaN` values in `Col5`.

Try:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col4': [0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3],
                  'Col5': ["Distinct", "Match", "Match", "Distinct", np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})

mapper = {
             0: "**Distinct**",
             1: "**Match**",
             2: "**Match**",
             3: "**Distinct**"
         }


df.loc[df.Col5.isna(), 'Col5'] = df[df.Col5.isna()]['Col4'].map(mapper)
```

You now get:

```
   Col4          Col5
0     0      Distinct
1     1         Match
2     2         Match
3     3      Distinct
4     0  **Distinct**
5     1     **Match**
6     2     **Match**
7     3  **Distinct**
```

This makes it easy to later change your mapping if you change your mind about the logic or replacement values.

Comment: I think his actual list is very long; so using mapper might not be a good idea

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I am assuming two things here:

1) You only have two entries for each number in Col 4

2) Both the entries with the same number in Col4 are placed adjacent to each other (That does not matter actually, if it is not the case, you can always sort the dataframe by Col4 and you will have this case)

The code is as follows:

```
df = df.replace(np.nan,"None")
txt = "None"
for i in range(df.Col4.size):
    if (df.loc[i,'Col5']=="None"):
        df.loc[i,'Col5'] = txt
        txt = "None"
    else: 
        txt = df.loc[i,'Col5']

txt = "None"
for i in reversed(range(df.Col4.size)):
    if (df.loc[i,'Col5']=="None"):
        df.loc[i,'Col5'] = txt
        txt = "None"
    else: 
        txt = df.loc[i,'Col5']
```

I am doing 3 steps here.

1) Replace all nan with a string, so that I do not have any datatype comparison issue while using the if.

2) The loop in ascending order. If the value in Col5 is 'None', then it is replaced by the value in 'txt'. Else, 'txt' variable is stores with the value in Col5.

3) The same loop in reverse order.

I hope this solves your problem.